# how to sort images in grid

Tags: iphone

hi i am new to iphone .what i did is displaying 20 images as grid using custom image picker and display them using imageview. here i treated every image as a button and display selected image using button tag value.now what i want is if i click any 4 images or a single image for 4 times that will be goes to end of the grid how can i done this pls help me if it possible post some code thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look for [Thee20 library](http://github.com/blog/389-three20-iphone-ui-goodness)